# empty list of windows version while installing using bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, catalina

I tried installing Windows 10 through bootcamp for the first time. All went well and windows installation started booting. But after the first language setup, the installation asked to select the windows version I wanted to install but it gave an empty list and I couldn't proceed. Anyone who knows an answer for this?

I am using:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Processor: 2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
OS X Version: Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76)
```

Windows I am installing is

```
Windows 10 Pro x64
Language en-US
File Size: ~3.63 GB
```

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of macOS? Where did you get the Windows ISO file? What language? Which edition of Windows? For example, the 1909  or 2004 update.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I updated question with specs

Comment: The current 64 bit english iso from Microsoft is named `Win10_2004_English_x64.iso`. The file size is 5.27 GB. You can download this iso file using Safari from [this Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).